# unable to import scrypt python 3.6 in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, import, scrypt

I am having a problem with this import in Windows.  Scrypt (version 0.8.6) was installed as part of the steem-python package using pip in a virtual environment.  I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community (version 15.9.2) in Windows 10.  When I try to import scrypt I get

```
>>> import scrypt
        Traceback (most recent call last): 
          File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\MM\source\repos\mysite\csenv\Lib\site-packages\scrypt\scrypt.py", line 15, in <module>
            _scrypt = cdll.LoadLibrary(imp.find_module('_scrypt')[1])
          File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
            return self._dlltype(name)
          File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
            self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
        OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I have tried this using the interactive window under the environment in Visual Studio as well as the command prompt.

I saw some references to needing openSSL.  OpenSSL 1.1.0j (64-bit) (the non lite version) is installed.

What am I missing?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after more searching, it seems that a specific version of openSSL is required - version 1.0.2 which includes libeay32.dll.  This file must also be included in c:\windows\system32.  Once this file is available, scrypt(and steem) import fine.